# Code logic should not allow query to go through but it still does PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I receive a `$_GET['id']` from the URL - I want it only numeric if not go to a 404 page. I believe I should work - but I have new relic that tells me otherwise and im stump. (note i'm working with legacy code so I apologize for the mysql_query commands and i'm aware I should be using PDO instead)

```
    if(isset($_GET['item']) && is_numeric($_GET['item'])) {
        $id = $_GET['item'];
    }
    else {
        $timestamp = date("Y-m-d");
        $get_item = json_encode($_GET['item']);
        $err = date("Y-m-d").": Get Item is wrong:".$get_item."\n";
        $file = "/logs/error_log_".$timestamp.".log";
        file_put_contents($file, $err, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/404.php' ) ;
    }

    $iquery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE products_id = $id";
    $iresult = mysql_query($iquery);

    if ($iresult == false) {
        $timestamp = date("Y-m-d");
        $err = date("Y-m-d").": SQL:".$iquery."\n";
        $file = "logs/error_log_".$timestamp.".log";
        file_put_contents($file, $err, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);        
        header( 'Location: http://www.examples.com/404.php' ) ;
    }
    $iline = mysql_fetch_array($iresult, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

according to my log the query itself receive nothign so $id receives nothing and my log file fires with nothing and new relic fires and tells me that my query is failing.

I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you expect the script to stop after you call `header()`, but there's nothing in your code that would cause that to happen. `header()` just adds an HTTP header to the response; it doesn't end your script. If you only want the query to be executed when `$_GET['id']` is numeric then you should do the query inside the first `if` block, not after the `else` block.

Comment: Or: exit after issuing the redirect.

Comment: So when I change the header for the redirect - the browser redirects the user but the script runs till the end and therefore the best way to cut things is an exit if I just dont want it to continue and save myself some time for processing.

Comment: Yeah, more or less. In general PHP will execute your entire script (up to an `exit` or `die`, anyway) before sending anything to the browser. If it stopped your script as soon as you called `header` that would be a problem, since you'd only ever be able to add one header—and sometimes you need to add many different headers.